# swiper api - how to stop a slide from overscrolling

Tags: javascript, swiper.js, sliders

I am using the iDangerous Swiper. By default if you touch and drag the first slide to the right, it allows you to kind of force it to the right, similar to how an iphone browser works, where it is kind of elastic and it only lets you drag a little. 
Is there a a paremeter to prevent this? I would also want the last slide to not be able to slide more to the left, since it will reveal what is underneath.

Answer (score 11):

found it... need to initialize with `resistanceRatio: 0`

```
var swiper = new Swiper(this.swiperContainer, {
    resistanceRatio: 0
});
```